# Copying file from Vcentre datastore to VM

Tags: python, salt-stack, vsphere, vcenter, pyvmomi

I use salt-stack and  pyvmomi module to  communicate with vcenter and create the VM. On this newly created VM I want to copy files(around 1 GB) from vcenter Datastore. InitiateFileTransferToGuest can be used to upload the file to VM but how can we copy files from datastore to vm ?

Answer (score 0):

The hackiest way I can think of is:

1. Save the 1GB file as .iso {either use MagicIso or inbuilt tools of
   linux}.
2. Now place the file in datastore.
3. Now when creating the vm,you need to set the cdrom to point to file-data instead of empty string.
4. You can either edit the vmx file or provide the vmx options
   while creating itself

> ```
>   ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
>     ide1:0.fileName = "/vmfs/volumes/5034a864-xxxxxx/data.iso"
>     ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
> ```

5. After powering on the guest, depending upon the guest, you can add a batch/shell to copy to its disk.
6. If required, you can use Invoke-VMScript powercli cmdlet to do operation 5 for you.

Cheers,
zXi

Comment: That i had in mind (wanted to avoid this process) apart from that we can also use salt-get-file to copy the file from master to minion

Comment: The pyvmomi salt allows only the operations supported from a VC objects. InitiateFileTransferToGuest is the pyvmomi call to transfer files to guests if tools are running. However, the API would need to be triggered from an ESXi server. 
You could try having a NFS datastore and add the addition of mounting {{mount.mounted}} to guest minions on tools running

Comment: Please share more detail about NFS and mounting datapoint on minion's.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about running rsync

- ESXi Host: enable SSH
- Some understanding of SSH keys

If this is a one off file transfer you could probably skip the first step.

Setup Public SSH Keys for vCentre.
ssh-keygen is found in `/usr/lib/vmware/openssh/bin`
ssh-keygen generates 2 files in `~/.ssh`: `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -P ""
```

On the remote host, store the public key 
If using ESXi 5 or below place `id_rsa.pub` in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
If using ESXi 5.5 or up public keys are located somewhere else so put `id_rsa.pub` in `/etc/ssh/keys-<username>/authorized_keys`

As a note you can store more than one key in this file.

To allow root access, change `PermitRootLogin no` to `PermitRootLogin yes` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.
To disable password login, ensure that `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` and `PasswordAuthentication` are set to `no`.

Restart the SSH service
ESXi - `/etc/init.d/SSH restart`
ESX - `service sshd reload`

Now that we have authentication sorted we can now copy files through an encrypted channel to our destination. 
Understanding how the ssh keys work will make your remote execution tasks so much more easier and streamlines deployment and management.

Rsync
The basic syntax of rsync is as follows rsync options source destination

Rsync over SSH

Some options - VM as local

Copy a File from a Remote Server(ESXi) to a Local Server(VM) with SSH

`rsync -avzhe ssh root@[vcentreIP]:/source_dir_to_copy/ /dest_dir_location/`

Copy a File from a Local Server(VM) to a Remote Server(ESXi) with SSH

`rsync -avzhe ssh /source_dest_to_copy/ root@[vcentreIP]:/dest_dir_location/`

Some options - ESXi as local - ESXi has not got rsync installed as default.

Copy a File from a Remote Server(VM) to a Local Server(ESXi) with SSH

`rsync -avzhe ssh root@[VMIP]:/source_dir_to_copy/ /dest_dir_location/`

Copy a File from a Local Server(ESXi) to a Remote Server(VM) with SSH

`rsync -avzhe ssh /source_dest_to_copy/ root@[VMIP]:/dest_dir_location/`

Another way is probably the option for you.

Using the same logic and method above. you could generate a set of keys between the two machines and use an agent to initiate the rsync command.

Copy a File from a VM to ESXi with SSH

`rsync -avzhe ssh root@[VMIP]:/source_dir_to_copy/ root@[vCentreIP]:/dest_dir_location/`

Copy a File from ESXi to VM with SSH

`rsync -avzhe ssh root@[vcentreIP]:/source_dir_to_copy/ root@[VMIP]:/dest_dir_location/`